# Retrieve kubernetes deploy yaml

Tags: kubernetes

I have deleted my deploy yaml (mistake). I need to know if kubernetes keep a copy of this file in the worker nodes. Can I get this file in any container of the worker nodes?.

- For example I retrieve files from pods because after delete my master container of my pods there are still running in the worker nodes

Comment: have you deleted the deployment from your cluster?

Comment: @juan have you got what you looking

Comment: @Spazzy757 I did not delete the deployment from the cluster.

Comment: then it seems that @harkeshkumar answer would allow you to get the yaml output of your deployment

Answer (score 4):

Inspect environment variables and Kubernetes deployment/service yaml

and support deployment name is `hello` then like you get yml
change `hello` with `deployment name`

```
kubectl get deploy/hello -o yaml
kubectl get svc/hello -o yaml
```

Comment: As I say master node goes down. After run commands above I get The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Comment: your minikube is down or kubectl is down

Comment: master node is down, I do not use minikube.

Comment: I only see docker containers

Comment: master node for what is down

Comment: I get The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?